# statistically compare 2 sharpe ratios

Tags: sharpe-ratio

I have a problem regarding comparing sharpe ratios of portfolios. As an example: I have constructed a portfolio from monthly data over 5 years, giving me a sharpe ratio of 0.85. I have a portfolio with similar stocks but with characteristics that they're majority owned by their employees, yielding sharpe ratio of 1.3.

I want to test if the ratio of 1.3 is significant different than the ratio of 0.85.

I'm using R for this so far.

Thanks for any help beforehand
Best
Emil

Comment: Use `SharpeR::sr_unpaired_test` for unpaired observations, or `SharpeR::sr_equality_test` for paired observations.

Answer (score 1):

This paper covers the topic and should be helpful:
https://alo.mit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/The-Statistics-of-Sharpe-Ratios.pdf